@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'warn' not working
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: ['prettier', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', 'plugin:promise/recommended'],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/no-parameter-properties': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    },
};


i have installed
"eslint": "^8.57.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.8.0", "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0", "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4", "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
and also the eslint extension. Also tried ESLint : restart eslint server  command
